# CSS last line element style

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<div class="archyvas-virselis">
    <a href="#"><img src="./img/virselis-archyvas.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="./img/virselis-archyvas.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="./img/virselis-archyvas.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="./img/virselis-archyvas.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="./img/virselis-archyvas.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="./img/virselis-archyvas.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="./img/virselis-archyvas.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="./img/virselis-archyvas.jpg" alt=""/></a>

</div>
```

For example in 1 line are 4 elements, and I want that 4th element of line `margin-right` will be `0`, it is possible to write that style ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  .archyvas-virselis a:nth-child(4n+4){ margin-right: 0}
```

for every 4 elements

or

```
 .archyvas-virselis a:nth-child(4){ margin-right: 0 }
```

for just the 4 element

keep in mind its only work for ie9 and above

Comment: Yep I nedd for every 4th element

Answer (score 1):

i would go with

```
a:nth-child(4n+4){
    margin-right:0;
}
```

on the basis that you might want the 4th to be margin right, but there might be more than 4 elements in a row (as per your HTML)

this is a css3 selector and may not work for older browsers (IE)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is the only way to do it without modifying the HTML. You can achieve it like this:

```
    jQuery('.archyvas-virselis a:nth-child(4n)').addClass('fourth-item');
```

and define styles for class *fourth-item*

but assuming you can do that, the main option is just to give it a *class="fourth-item"*, then do:

```
a.fourth-item { /* ... */ }
```